# In R, switch uppercase to lowercase and vice-versa in a string

Tags: r

I am familiar with the functions `toupper()` and `tolower()`, however that doesn't exactly give what I want here. Here is an example of the string I have and the string I want:

```
this = "This is the string THAT I have!"
that = "tHIS IS THE STRING that i HAVE!"
```

simple enough to describe with an example, harder to implement (i think).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sort of curious if there is a better way than:

```
chartr(x = this,
       old = paste0(c(letters,LETTERS),collapse = ""),
       new = paste0(c(LETTERS,letters),collapse = ""))
```

Helpful observation by @Joris in the comments that `?chartr` notes that you can use character ranges, avoiding the `paste`:

```
chartr("a-zA-Z", "A-Za-z",this)
```

Comment: which is actually documented in `?tolower`. I'd do `chartr("a-zA-Z", "A-Za-z",this)` which is essentially the same and doesn't require `paste`

Comment: this is an intuitive solution (to both of you), thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that works with characters that aren't between `a` and `z` / `A` and `Z` :

```r
text <- "aBàÉ"

up <- gregexpr("\\p{Lu}", text, perl=TRUE)
lo <- gregexpr("\\p{Ll}", text, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(text,up)[[1]] <- tolower(regmatches(text,up)[[1]])
regmatches(text,lo)[[1]] <- toupper(regmatches(text,lo)[[1]])
text
#> [1] "AbÀé"
```